# Which filed is best Dynamic CRM or hardcore Dot Net Web developer

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I am a dot web developer and recently I got an offer for CRM technical consultant from a company so I'm confused about that should I accept that offer or proceed with my recent field. so I need expert opinion from all you ?

Which filed is best Dynamic CRM or hardcore Dot net Web developer ?

Need expert opinion.
Please provide a reason too.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Career suggestions and Job related queries are not suitable for Stackoverflow portal.

Comment: question really helped me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Dynamics CRM developer you can be a web, backend, database, enterprise and/or report developer. All in the middle of the Microsoft product/technology portfolio (SQL Server, SharePoint, Office, Azure and Visual Studio/.Net to name a few).

It's a fast moving area and you will likely be working with the newest technology.

Generally speaking, in our business it's a wise decision to specialize. Finding good web developers can be a challenge, finding good Dynamics CRM developers is even harder. Logical consequence is that the market value of CRM developers is better.